# Yoneda lemma - Why is $\textrm{Nat}(\textrm{Hom}(A,-),F)$ a set?

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a locally small category and $F:\mathcal{C}\to \textrm{Set}$ is a covariant functor. Since every class in bijection with a set is a set, and the Yoneda lemma establishes that $\textrm{Nat}(\textrm{Hom}(A,-),F)\cong F(A),$ then as long as $\textrm{Nat}(\textrm{Hom}(A,-),F)$ is a class, it will also be a set. It will be a class as long as all of its elements are sets. But natural transformations between functors in $[\mathcal{C},\textrm{Set}]$ associate a morphism to each of the class-many objects in $\mathcal{C}$ and should not themselves be sets! I've read multiple times that $\textrm{Nat}(\textrm{Hom}(A,-),F)$ is a functor from $\mathcal{C}\times \textrm{Set}^{\mathcal{C}}$ to $\textrm{Set}$, but the natural transformations themselves do not seem to be sets, so why should this be the case?

My title is very similar to [Yoneda Lemma - why is $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_A,X)$ a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245952/yoneda-lemma-why-is-mathscr-a-textop-textbfseth-a-x-a-set), but I think the question is a bit different. This question [Why do natural transformations between set valued functors from locally small categories form a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895740/why-do-natural-transformations-between-set-valued-functors-from-locally-small-ca) also seems relevant.

Comment: As you say, it is sometimes not even a class. But then what is it? At any rate, it is in bijection with a set and that is often good enough.

Comment: Can you elaborate how your question differs from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895740/ so that its answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1896385 (and especially the last paragraph) does not answer your question?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov The thing that trips me up about that paragraph is that I think it defines $\textrm{Nat}(\textrm{Hom}(A,-),F)$ to be $FA$ and that just seems like cheating to me.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I suppose that in that case you answer is saying that $\textrm{Nat}(\textrm{Hom}(A,-),F)$ is not in fact a set. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, Nat(Hom(A,-),F) is not even a priori a well-defined class. Each individual natural transformation (between any two functors) is well-defined, but the class of all of them is not. The Yoneda lemma gives you a way to define that class when the source functor is representable. But this is no more cheating than, say, the axiom of infinity in set theory, and in fact is less cheating. Explicitly, the set whose elements can be identified with natural numbers exists due to an axiom, whereas a class whose elements can be identified with natural transformations exists by the Yoneda lemma.